# Can I remove a file frome inside` vi `?

Tags: vi

I want to open several files with `vi` or even `less` and delete those I don't care without going back to the shell and go to the next.

Comment: I might be wrong, but you can escape to a shell with `!`, and I think execute a command like this: `!rm whateverfile.txt`.

Comment: @ultrasawblade Sounds plausible.

Comment: What do you mean "remove" (close it, delete it, something else), and what do you mean when you say "without going back and go to the next"?  Going back to what?

Answer (score 0):

The question has many interpretations, but I guess you want some sort of automated visualizator which asks if you want to keep/delete a file. One method could be this:

Given a list of files:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$@"; do
    less "$f"
    # head -n 10
    rm -i "$f"
done
```

Given a directory which contains ẗhe files:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$1"

for f in "$dir/*"; do
    less "$f"
    # head -n 10
    rm -i "$f"
done
```

In both scripts you'll have to exit the `less` process by pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> before you can select to either keep or remove the file. You can use the `head -n 10` command instead to avoid that and display only the first 10 lines.

Run these from a command line and give them the correct parameters. Good Luck.

Comment: You can replace the entirety of these scripts from `echo` through `esac` (inclusive) with simply `rm -i "$f"` (I also suggest escaping the file name in the invocation, to guard against special characters). `-i` makes rm ask for confirmation, which gives you the yes/no prompt (and as an added bonus respects the user's locale settings).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've corrected the script to use your method. Thank you.

Comment: It work very well, thank you arielnmz and Michael.It return to the shell but it's automated and fluid.

Answer (score 0):

With vi, you can open multiple files, either explicitly or by wildcard, e.g.:

```
vi 1.txt 2.txt
vi *.txt
```

Once they're open, you can navigate between them a number of ways.  `:ls` will show a list of the open files.  To switch, you can use either the name or the index, e.g. `b1` to open file 1 in the list, or `b 1.txt` to switch to the file explicitly.

`:n` and `:p` will act as next and previous respectively.

`:bd` will close the file.